# Android Actionbar Tabs on bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I agree before-hand with anyone who wants to make the argument that tabs should be at the top of the screen, but I can't control the requirements for my app :) . I have to build an app with tabs at the bottom of the screen. I'm using SDK 14 and Actionbars. Is this even possible? I have already built a layout with the tabs at the bottom, but when I add the tabs to the ActionBar, they are automatically rendered at the top of the screen.

Any ideas would be really appreciated, and thank you all for taking the time to read this post.

Comment: Do you need to use the ActionBar for tabs or can you use a TabHost?

Comment: I'm not sure which is the better route. I started off with ActionBar since that's what the developer's guide recommends. I'm also on SDK 14. I'm starting to consider using a TabHost. Is it possible to place the tabs at the bottom using a TabHost?

Comment: Yes, you can put them on the bottom with a TabHost.

Comment: From what I've read, the Tabhost is deprecated (though still supported) and the new way of doing tabs is using the ActionBar and the addTab() method. If I wanted to continue using the ActionBar, is there a way for me to place the tabs at the bottom?

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated, not TabHost. As far as I know, ActionBar tabs cannot go across the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tabhost for requirement,and inside tab.xml you can write below code . This will work fine .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
                 </FrameLayout>
          <TabWidget 
             android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:background="#000000" />
          </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```